# Compile time error from Eigen: THE_EVAL_EVALTO_FUNCTION_SHOULD_NEVER_BE_CALLED_FOR_DENSE_OBJECTS

Tags: c++, stdvector, eigen

I've been struggling to write a utility function to convert between an Eigen `Matrix` and an STL `vector`.  I've condensed my code down to:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

template <int Flags=Eigen::RowMajor, typename Derived>
std::vector<typename Derived::Scalar>
eigenToStdVector(const Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>& b)
{
  typedef typename Derived::Scalar Scalar;
  std::vector<Scalar> out(b.size());
  Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Flags> >
    (out.data(), b.rows(), b.cols()) = b/*.derived()*/;
  return out;
}

int
main ()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXf v(2,4);
  v << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;
  std::cout << v << std::endl;

  for (auto i : eigenToStdVector(v))
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (auto i : eigenToStdVector<Eigen::ColMajor>(v.transpose()))
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and I don't understand why including the (commented) `.derived()` line causes the compile to succeed.  If anyone could comment as to why including this is necessary I'd be most grateful!

I'm using GCC 4.8 and Eigen 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `DenseBase` instead of the too general `EigenBase` base classe. This discrepancy will probably go away in 3.3.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work well for me…  Still getting my head around Eigen's structure, it all seems somewhat baroque but presume it's all there for a reason!